# Perl regex replace?

Tags: regex, perl

Why does this work:

```
$my_str=~s/://g;
```

But this does not:

```
$my_str=~s/:://g;
```

I have a string that looks something like this: `::this:is:my:string` and I need to remove the `::` but not touch the `:`.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: are you doing one after the other ?

Comment: It works for me.  At least it does with a string that looks *exactly* like "::this:is:my:string".  I have no idea what it will do with a string that looks "something like" that.  If you want real answers, show real code.

Comment: Please include your perl version in your question.

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of your script. If you can still run the script without warnings, post your code.

Comment: Oh you know what. This script was written by another guy in my department and he commented out use strict; and use warnings; This explains why I was so puzzled. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Works fine for me:

```
$ echo "::this:is:my:string" | perl -ne "s/:://g; print;"
this:is:my:string
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you don't have any typos in your code?  And that this substitution is in fact the problem?  The following program worked for me:

```
my $var = '::a:b:c::';
print "$var\n";
$var =~ s/:://g;
print "$var\n";
```

Output:

```
$ perl test.pl
::a:b:c::
a:b:c
$
```

Edit to add a couple suggestions:

1. Print the variable immediately before and after the substitution.
2. No immediately the problem at hand, but if you only need to remove the :: at the beginning of the string, you may want to add a ^ to the regex to indicate that.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I can think of that would cause `$my_str =~ s/:://g;` fail:

1. `$my_str` doesn't contains what you say it contains.
2. `pos($my_str)` is set.

To make sure `$my_str` contains what you think it does, you could use [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper), but make sure to do `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` before using `Dumper`.

But first, make sure you aren't doing something like

```
if ($my_str =~ /.../g) {
   ...
   $my_str =~ s/:://g;
   ...
}
```

`if ($my_str =~ /.../g)` is a common mistake, and it could cause this problem. (I don't know why since it doesn't even make sense conceptually.) If so, get rid of the `g` in the `if` condition.